Why Does the Sigmoid Output Layer in a Binary Feedforward Neural Network Represent the Probability of the Positive Class (Label = 1)?
I'm a beginner who just started to study deep learning. I recently learned that in a feedforward neural network with a binary output and a Bernoulli distribution, the output of the sigmoid function represents the probability that the label is 1. I`m curious why it cannot be the other way round (probability of the label being 0). Is it just for the convenience?

Related...you don't even have to use the 0/1 convention.

The post helped greatly. Thanks!

It is a convention.
Ultimately, what is important is that the objective function, likely to be log-likelihood in your context has to be computed based on the convention that you have chosen.
It would be great to follow the convention that most have adopted to reduce the risk of miscommunication/ misinterpretation.
